# Javascript Function after ajax runs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert a cookie after ajax runs and does its thing.  Ajax is working for the most part.  I do have a pesky error I cant sort out.  But after that runs I want it to insert a cookie and hide a div.

```
$('button').click(function() {
var name2 = $('#username').val();
var email2 = $('#email').val();
console.log('starting ajax');
$.ajax({
    url: "insert.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        email: email2,
        username: name2
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(dataParsed);
        TermsAndConditions();
    }
});

});


});
```

The additional script I want to run:

```
function TermsAndConditions() {
    days = 20;
    myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = 'TermsAndConditions=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
}

var cookie = document.cookie.split(';')
    .map(function(x) {
        return x.trim().split('=');
    })
    .filter(function(x) {
        return x[0] === 'TermsAndConditions';
    })
    .pop();

if (cookie && cookie[1] === 'Accepted') {
    $(".readme").hide();
}

});
```

This is just a simple acknowledgment that a user click the button and it runs the script.  I cant seem to get this working though.

Side Note:
My ajax works but returns an error in concole.

```
VM1790:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (index.php:189)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

My insert.php

```
    $name = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO index_acknowledge (email, username)
VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->execute([$email, $name ]);
$stmt = null;

?>
```

Comment: why doesn't the php just set the cookie?

Comment: Sounds like your server is not returning JSON

Comment: @epascarello I want it to all run in that one javascript.  Makes it "easier" lol To read and troubleshoot i suppose.

Comment: You need to fix the JSON error first since the syntax error its generating will prevent the rest of the JavaScript from executing.

Comment: For starters `insert.php` is not `echo json_encode($objectOrAssocArray);`ing, so there is no JSON, hence your error.

Comment: @StackSlave ok got that JSON error fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my issue was an error being returned by the JSON and was stopping my script.  In order to fix this I added a return json to my insert.php file.

my insert.php fix

```
...
$stmt->execute([$email, $name ]);
$stmt = null;
echo json_encode($stmt);
```

This is my fixed jquery

```
$(function() {
    function TermsAndConditions() {
        days = 20;
        myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = 'TermsAndConditions=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    }

    var cookie = document.cookie.split(';')
        .map(function(x) {
            return x.trim().split('=');
        })
        .filter(function(x) {
            return x[0] === 'TermsAndConditions';
        })
        .pop();

    if (cookie && cookie[1] === 'Accepted') {
        $(".readme").hide();
    }

    $('#acknowledge').on('click', function() {
        TermsAndConditions();
        return false;
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        var name2 = $('#username').val();
        var email2 = $('#email').val();
        console.log('starting ajax');
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                email: email2,
                username: name2
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(dataParsed);
                TermsAndConditions();
                $(".readme").hide();
            }
        });

    });



});
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to reload your page. The entire point of AJAX is so you don't have to.

Comment: It doesnt hide the div if it doesnt reload for some reason

Comment: Then write the code that `.hide()`s the div you want to hide.

Comment: @StackSlave `Like this? ``` if (cookie && cookie[1] === 'Accepted') {
        $(".readme").hide();
    } ```

Comment: Fixed my answer